# Using VIF, Interaction Effects, polynomial associations for feature selection in multiple linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, feature-selection, interaction, polynomial, variance-inflation-factor

Is there a guide, tradition, or accepted practice on what to take into account and in what sequence between VIF, interaction effects, variable transformations and polynomial associations when performing feature selection for multiple linear regression models?

Comment: What makes feature selection a desirable goal?  How do you corrrect standard errors to account for large biases in them caused by feature selection?

Comment: I'm still building my knowledge base in data science and want to understand this aspect of machine learning in all its strengths and weaknesses. Which course other than feature selection  would you advise here Frank? Enlighten me.

Comment: Also inform me, of the answer to my question, disregarding the limitations of that approach for the moment.

Comment: He's written a book, *Regression Modelling Strategies*, that discusses this issue extensively. You can also read through some of our existing threads categorized under the [tag:feature-selection] tag. This issue has been discussed extensively on the site many times.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I haven't been able to find a question that answers my particular question about the interoperability of all these topics (VIF, interaction, polynomial association variable transformation). 
That's why I had to ask this question.
I would appreciate it if you could help me discover the answer.

Comment: Feature selection is usually doomed to not find the right features unless you have orthogonal features and an enormous sample size.  Instead concentrate on penalization (shrinkage) and data reduction (unsupervised learning).  The latter will reduce the predictor space down to what is stable.   Sparse principal components analysis is one of the recommended data reduction approaches.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks. I'm not yet familiar with the concepts that you have mentioned. I'll learn more about them.